# Android: extends TabActivity deprecated, when will this cause problems?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an app, and I wanted to use Tabs for menu, however when I extend TabActivity in my class it says it's deprecated. 
So my question is, when will this cause problems? Will this affect only like Android L phones or what?

Can I still use it without having problems? I only have 2 months left to make app, so I don't have time to learn about fragments, from quickly glancing over documentation it seems too long to bother spending time learning fragments.

Comment: Create an activity with a tab navigation system when creating your project. It will use Tab Fragments. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally `@Deprecated` means that this feature will no longer be developed (for example no bugs will be fixed) and in some future release this will be removed completely.

However I know no example of feature or function being removed from Android API. Goolge usually tells us:

> Hey, we invented something awesome, but it can no longer be
>   achieved using present mechanisms, so we implemented it from scratch! Please switch to our brand new mechanism whenever you will have time.

To summarize:
Using `@Deprecated` methods will not cause any problems by sole fact that they are deprecated. This features are obsolete now and there is something better, faster and more reliable in Android API that you should be using now.